lcm in terms of gcd in a commutative monoid with cancellation laws
Let $M$ be a commutative monoid with cancellation, $a$,$b \in M$, and $d$ a $\text{gcd}(a,b)$. Then, $\frac{ab}{d}$ is a $\text{lcm}(a,b)$.
It is obvious that such a fraction is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$, but how to show that it divides all other common multiples?

Is  this proof working?

It is not true that $\gcd(a,b)$ exists $\Rightarrow {\rm lcm}(a,b)$ exists. Rather,  ${\rm lcm}(a.b)$ exists $!\iff! \gcd(ac,bc),$ exists for all $,c,,$ see the dupe and its links. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque, Do you know an example for which this statement fails? I took the result from Hachenberger's book Topics in Galois Fields (Lemma 1.2.18).

Please read the linked dupe. Your context may be a gcd domain / monoid, where all gcds exist by hypothesis.

If so, then you can use this proof. $\ \ $
